# can I find via GDB if a variable belong to heap or stack?

Tags: c, linux, gdb

My breakpoint points to a variable. (points somewhere. Can I figure out if somewhere belongs to the heap or the stack?)

is there any way to find where is the beginning and the end of the stack? is there any way to find where is the beginning and the end of the heap?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `info proc mappings` for `/proc` info about your memory layout.

Comment: This will not work on a core dump loaded on GDB. In that case `maintenance info sections` migh help.

Comment: Please add for completeness, that the address space that belongs to stack is titled as `[stack]` in the last column of the output.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think gdb will tell you directly, but you can compare addresses to figure out what range it falls into. You'd have to look through the library source code to find ithem, but the heap manager will *typically* have some internal variables to track where the heap is.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your compiler, you may have a symbol like `__stack` or `__stack_end` in the debug info. If so, you may use these symbols to compare your pointer against them.